# Question on the "range" of $f(x)=2^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From a high school (Algebra II) quiz:

**If the domain of $f(x)=2^x$ is the positive rational numbers, what is the range?**

Since "range" can be ambiguous at this level, let's assume it means the image, not the codomain.

*The solution provided by the teacher was that the range was also the positive rational numbers.*

No matter how you interpret range, that can't be right since there are obviously irrational numbers in the image (let $x=\frac12$).

If the answer provided was the positive *real* numbers I'd accept it as meaning codomain not image since $f$ maps the domain into but not onto the reals.

So my question is the following: the image is a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and is described as

$\{y\in\mathbb{R}: y=2^x \space\text{for some}\space x\in\mathbb{Q}\}$

and actually a unique $x$ in this case [added: and $x>0$].

Is there another way to describe it or think about this problem at a high-school level, or it is just the teacher not fully considering what he/she asked and answered?

Comment: **Hint**: the given function is strictly monotone increasing.

Comment: Yes and you can express with $log$ or $ln$ if you really want to, but I was thinking more conceptually, is there a better way to think about it and give a correct answer at the high school level or just assume the teacher meant something simpler and move on.

Comment: The actual image of the function is as you described, but if it can be taken to be the same as Q because they're both countable, then both can be seen to be the same as N because N is by definition countable as well. So the function is a function from N to N?  Probably best to just ask your teacher to clarify

Comment: See $2^x$ can't be $0$ and -ve for any $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ so range is $(0,\infty)$

Comment: Well there are bijections between N, Q and the image that make that work; I'm not sure the particular high school student I know here is going to appreciate that.  I am pretty sure the objective was NOT illustrating countable sets and the (surprising at first) fact that N and Q have the same size!

Comment: @LuckyChouhan clearly if you assume range means codomain, since this function maps into that interval not onto it. In high school range is often taught to mean image.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 Oh yeah! our domain is not $\mathbb{R}$ it is $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: I don't think there is a "clean" answer here - it is what it is - but good discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that there is *no* sense in which the range is the positive rational numbers. There are three issues of varying importance:

- Most significantly, many outputs of $f$, such as $f(\frac12) = \sqrt2$, are not rational.
- Also, many positive rational numbers are *not* values of $f$. (This is not a *mistake*, if we're talking about a codomain instead of a range, but it's still awkward.) For example, there is no rational $x$ such that $f(x) = 3$, because $\log_2 3$ is irrational.
- Also, "positive" is not the best cutoff we can give: if $x$ is a positive rational number, then $f(x) > 1$.

The image definitely is $\{y \in \mathbb R: y = 2^x \text{ for some } x \in \mathbb Q \text{ with } x>0\}$, just by definition. We have to be careful about $x$ being a *positive* real number. Aside from that, we could also write $$\{y \in \mathbb R : y > 1 \text{ and } \log_2 y \in \mathbb Q\}.$$ This is arguably slightly simpler, but not a lot simpler.

If we wanted to define a *nice* codomain for the function, we could take the interval $(1,\infty)$, or $[1,\infty)$, or $(0,\infty)$ (the positive real numbers), or even all of $\mathbb R$. The image of $f$ is dense in the interval $(1,\infty)$, so there's no good "middle ground" between the image and the interval $(1,\infty)$.